# How to grab value back from external script in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid. I want to pass a full path variable to a perl script, where I do some work on it and then pass it back. So I have:

```
    echo "Backing up: $f ";
    $write_file="$(perl /home/spider/web/foo.com/public_html/gen-path.cgi $f)";
    echo "WRITE TO: $write_file \n";
```

However, this gives me:

```
Backing up: /home/spider/web/foo.com/public_html/websites-uk/uk/q/u
backup-files-all.sh: line 7: =backup-uk-q-u.tar.gz: command not found
WRITE TO:  \n
```

I can't work out why its not saving the output into `$write_file`. I must be missing something (bash isn't my prefered language, which is why I'm passing to Perl as I'm a lot more fluent in that :))

Comment: `$write_file="$(perl /home/spider/web/foo.com/public_html/gen-path.cgi $f)";
`?  looks like unexpected prefix `$`, maybe you mean `write_file="$(perl /home/spider/web/foo.com/public_html/gen-path.cgi $f)";`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your variable `write_file` already exists, the command `$write_file="something"` will translate to `="something"`<sup>(1)</sup>.

When *setting* a variable, leave off the `$` - you only need it if you want the *value* of the variable.

In other words, what you need is (note no semicolons needed):

```sh
write_file="$(perl /home/spider/web/foo.com/public_html/gen-path.cgi $f)"
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> It can be even *hairier* if it *is* set to something. For example, the code:

```sh
write_file=xyzzy
$write_file="something"
```

will result in `something` being placed into a variable called `xyzzy`, *not* `write_file` :-)